# Serialise array as single XML element in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Say I have the C# code

```
class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public string[] bar;
}

var foo = new Foo
{
    bar = new[] { "1", "2", "3" }
};
```

How do I serialise `Foo.bar` as `<bar>1,2,3</bar>`?

Comment: Use `string.Join` to fuse the three strings together and then make the `bar` element be a `string` not a `string[]`

Comment: @Flydog57 if possible, I'd prefer to transform into a single string at time of serialisation

Comment: Write custom xml serializer

Comment: @T.S. okay thank you, I was hoping for a built-in feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need create additional property to serialize array as single element

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo
        {
            bar = new[] { "1", "2", "3" }
        };
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, foo);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string[] bar;

    [XmlElement("bar")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public string BarValue
    {
        get
        {
            if(bar == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return string.Join(",", bar);
        }
        set
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                bar = Array.Empty<string>();
            }
            else
            {
                bar = value.Split(",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <bar>1,2,3</bar>
</Foo>
```